# Comma after a long introductory phrase

Tags: punctuation, commas, clauses

Please help me with commas in the following sentence:

> As an example of the successful use of such a model **[,]** one can mention SymPy computer algebra system **[,]** which uses Python as a main user interface.

Is it necessary to write the comma after *model*? I am not sure whether we can consider "As an example of the successful use of such a model" as an introductory phrase. Also, I am not sure about the second comma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A comma is required after *model* because, although the phrase comes at the beginning of the sentence, it is a weak interruption. That is to say, you would still have a viable sentence if you removed it.

You need the second comma, because what follows is a supplementary, not an integrated, relative clause.

Comment: +1, but I think there second could be optional dependant on context. Tell me if you agree with my answer.

Comment: @Jon Hanna. For the relative clause to be integrated rather than supplementary there would have to be more than one SymPy computer algebra system.

Comment: Right you are. I asked because something made me lack confidence in my answer, and that's exactly how I should have been thinking.

Comment: _Integrated_ and _supplementary_, by the way, are the terms used in 'The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language' in place of the more usual _defining / non-defining_ or _restrictive / non-restrictive_.

Comment: Funny, I half-suspect that was what led my thinking astray, though were I more used to them in such a context, they probably wouldn't have.

Answer (score 1):

As far as relative pronouns go, a little brown book insists on the comma after "which" because it usually introduces nonessential elements.  It opens a relative clause that has more weight than "that."

[Companion website to the Little, Brown Book](http://wps.ablongman.com/long_fowler_lbh_9/12/3213/822594.cw/index.html)

The exercises on this site are excellent!

Comment: (9th edition, section 28c).

Comment: More than a few allow *which* in either case though. But +1 because thinking about whether *that* could serve or would be plain wrong can help tell the cases apart, and would have saved me from the answer I deleted as incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Both commas are ok, as they are used to indicate where the reader/speaker might pause for a moment, whether reading aloud or silently.

Comment: But then that just gives us the question "are these places where the reader/speaker might pause for a moment?" While it can be a good intuitive guide to someone fluent in the language to think "would I pause", it doesn't really *tell* us anything, and it can lead us astray. (I'll admit that it is how I decide this in practice while actually writing, but I do find it sometimes leaves me with some strangely placed commas when I come back to what I've written).